# how to get the JSON out of the jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: json, jackson

We need to bulid up a json payload to send to a rest endpoint. Our org uses Jackson.  The only way to build up the json (without creating dozens of nested empty pojos) is as follows:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
ObjectNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
ObjectNode content = mapper.createObjectNode();
rootNode.set("someContent", content);
content.put("somekey","someval");
... lots more nested objects created here...
```

Ok, so now I have a complex json object in the mapper. How do I get it out?
E.g. How do I get a json string out of it suitable for sending to an REST api as post payload?

There are various examples of setting up pretty print, but these revolve around jsonizing a single java object (which I am not doing), or outputting to streams or files, not a simple String.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps use [`ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object)):

```
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(rootNode));
```